# Seemingly weird connectivity issue on Windows

Tags: windows

I have started facing a weird connectivity issue on my Windows machine.

I have 2 different phones, say A and B, and I generally use either one with the hotspot on for accessing the internet on the Windows laptop.

Today, for some weird reason, I can access the internet if I use the hotspot from mobile A but not from B and even worse, the hotspot from B connects for about 5-15 seconds after restarting the laptop, and then it shows Connected, Secured the entire time but when I try to use any website, it says not connected.

At first, I thought maybe phone B had an issue but I checked with another laptop I have and that one connects to both phones' hotspots without any issue.

So, it looks like there is some problem with the Windows laptop itself.

Please help me find a fix for this as phone B is the one which I use regularly for the hotspot.

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it's not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to say that is not a normal behavior between WiFi in Windows and Hotspots but you know what, it is.

Normally, when it happens and mostly based on what you are saying that it happens only with one laptop, the current connection is kinda "stuck", so, from my experience what I have done to solve this kind of issues is:

-Go to the WiFi icon in the lower right corner from the taskbar and right click over it.

-Select "Open Network& Internet Settings".

-In the new Window, from the list on the left, select "WiFi".

-Then a little bit on the right select "Manage known networks".

-Select the name of the Hotspot that is giving you issues and then click on "Forget".

-Turn the WiFi off in the computer.

-Turn the Hostpot off in the phone that has the issue.

-Turn the Hotspot back on in that phone.

-Turn the WiFi back on in the computer with the issue.

-Finally, create the connections from scratch, as if it was the very first time.

That should solve the issue.

In the worst scenario that the same thing happens, we can also try to uninstall the driver for the WiFi card from the Device Manager as admin, restart the computer to force Windows to reinstall the WiFi card, and create the connection from scratch.

I hope it works for you as it has done it for me in a lot of cases.

Regards.